# What is a good way to display a 3d sphere rotating in 2d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, 2d

how i can make a 2d planet appear to rotate, if the planets map is rectangular pixel map.
Im curious if anyone knows a good way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to either make a 2d animation giving it different textures to appear to be rotating or have a 3d sphere that isn't a solid color actually rotating. There are a couple videos on YouTube on how to do 2d planet rotation that should help you out.